# how to fix exception Problem Of MathCalculationException?

Tags: java, scala

In division function thrown a MathCalculationException but in console it's showing ArithmeticException,I want to show ArithmeticException ?

```
 class OverFlowException extends RuntimeException
  class UnderFlowException extends RuntimeException
  class MathCalculationException extends Exception("Division by 0")
  object PocketCalculator{
    def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
      val result = x+y
      if( x > 0 && y > 0 && result < 0 ) throw  new OverFlowException
      else if (x < 0 && y <0 && result > 0) throw  new UnderFlowException
      else result
    }
    def subtract(x: Int, y: Int):Int = {
      val result = x - y
      if(x > 0 && y <0 && result < 0 ) throw  new OverFlowException
      else if (x < 0 && y > 0 && result > 0) throw  new UnderFlowException
      else result
    }
    def multiply(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
      val result = x * y
      if( x > 0 && y > 0 && result < 0) throw new OverFlowException
      else if (x < 0 && y < 0 && result < 0) throw new OverFlowException
      else if ( x < 0 && y > 0 && result > 0) throw new UnderFlowException
      else if( x > 0 && y < 0 && result > 0) throw new UnderFlowException
      else result
    }
    def divide(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
      val result = x/y
      if(y == 0) throw new MathCalculationException
      else result
    }

  }
  // println(PocketCalculator.add(Int.MaxValue, 9))
  println(PocketCalculator.divide(0, 0))
```

expected : Exception$`MathCalculationException`
actual : ArithmeticException: / by zero

Comment: you first divide `val result = x/y` and then check the value of y `if (y == 0)`

Comment: Use lazy val or change the order of checking

Comment: You don't need `result`. Do the math op (`+`, `-`, `*`, or `/`) at the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

I'Ve annotated your code slightly:

```
def divide(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
  val result = x/y // ArithmeticException raised here
  if(y == 0) throw new MathCalculationException // never reached
  else result
}
```

You can instead:

```
def divide(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
  if(y == 0) throw new MathCalculationException
  x/y
}
```